# How to use inner class in python?

Tags: python, oop

```
class Tesla_car:
    def __init__(self,yourname):
        self.name = yourname
        print("Hey'%s',I am a bot and I will tell you about....." %self.name)
        self.cells = self.batteries()


    def material(self,model_no):
        self.model = model_no
        print("your car",self.model," made from aluminium")
    def color(self,color):
        self.color = color
        print("the color of your car is:'%s'" %self.color)
        
        class batteries:
            def __init__(self):
                pass
            def materials(self):
                self.battery_name = "Tesla tabless 4680 cells"
                self.chemicals = "Tesla uses Lithium-Nickle-cobalt-magnesium(NMC) mixed in 8:1:1 ratio"
    EV_car = Tesla_car('Blah')
    EV_car()
```

Hey everyone, I am trying to use nested classes but whenever I try to use the inner class by writing `self.cells = self.batteries()` It raises an error:"Tesla_car' object has no attribute 'batteries"
How do I fix it

Comment: You normally *don't* use nested classes in Python.  What makes you think this would be at all useful here?

Comment: *Why* do you think a nested class is necessary or appropriate? That said, you have indentation issues that make it appear that `batteries` is local to `color`, not a class attribute.

Comment: [zen of python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) - Flat is better than nested. What do you think is the scope of your nested class anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
self.batteries()
```

to

```
Tesla_car.batteries()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're trying to compose objects, but in the wrong way.

Actually your classes reflect a perfect irl scenario for implementing **composition**: cars are equipped (composed) with a set of different objects, batteries included.

When using composition, you'd typically define `TeslaCar` and `Batteries` as separate classes, and then you would assign an instance of `Batteries` to one of `TeslaCar` instance variables. E.g.:

```
class Batteries:
    def __init__(self):
        ...

class TeslaCar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.batteries = Batteries()
        ...
```

The above code is just a simple skeleton of how composition is implemented, but you can adapt it to your case very easily.

Finally FYI, avoid nesting classes at all. It's unpythonic and you'll discover that it's useless as soon as you dive deep into simple oop patterns like composition and inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

your `batteries` inner class is wrongly indented.

Currently it is inside the `color` method instead of being at the same level as the method.

```
class TeslaCar:

    def color(...):
        ...
        class Batteries:
           ...
```

instead, do:

```
class TeslaCar:

    def color(...):
       ...

    class Batteries:
       ...
```

Comment: btw I used proper classes names to respect PEP8